# Removes duplicates in array using user defined method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to remove the duplicates in this array:

```
int[] array = {20, 100, 10, 80, 70, 1, 0, -1, 2, 10, 15, 300, 7, 
           6, 2, 18, 19, 21, 9, 0};
```

Using a custom method.

how do I go about this?

Comment: Have you preserve order?

Comment: One approach is by writing code.

Comment: *"Using a custom method"* As opposed to what? Do you know of a *standard* method doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashSet`

You can try this:

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

Set stores only unique elements.

Convert back your set to array using `myset.toArray()`

Comment: ... and convert it back to a list.

Comment: yea I forgot. Done!